# PreparedStatement does not work with Google SQL cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am developing an application based on google sql cloud . The Mysql database is local.
The code below to insert a row works :

```
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement(); 
String sql = "INSERT INTO USER(name) VALUES ('smith')";
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

However, the code below, that uses PreparedStatement rather that Statement does not work :

```
String sql = "insert into USER(email) values(?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setString(1, email);
int success = pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

No rows are inserted in the database and success = 0 (return code for error)

Thanks for your help

Comment: I think this issue is not specific to your local CloudSQL configuration, but rather to the internals of `prepareStatement` vs `createStatement`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But could you explain a little more what you mean by the internals ?

Comment: "Internals" -> specific behaviour of those methods, in which my knowledge is limited and therefore can't help you.

Comment: Problem solved. The problem came from my google app engine installation in intellij. I reinstalled it and the problem disappeared

Comment: Write your solution as an answer and accept it.